# Own android app can't access internet on emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, connection

I'm modifying an android app and I want to test it with an emulator on my machine so I can examine the apps data.

I'm experiencing some internet connectivity issue with my own app but the browser on the emulator works without any problems.
Now I already read a dozen of articles regarding this subject but so far there has not been a solution that works for me.

I tried: 
- adding dns-server to startup params. 
- Disable LAN, only enable wifi of my laptop
- Toggle 3G connectivity in the emulator
- Add GSM Modem Support to emulator
- Restart Eclipse
- Restart Laptop
- Double check the internet permissions in the manifest

I'm running out of options here and hope some people could provide me with some wisdom.

I'm running all of this on 
- Mac OS X - 10.6.8 
- Eclipse Indigo Service Release 1 - Build id: 20110916-0149
- Android MinSdk 7
- Emulator is using SDK level 16

A small footnote, I don't have any issues regarding internet problems on a real device. I'm able to run the application on a Google Nexus with Android 4.1.1

Any information would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have the INTERNET permission in your manifest? Without code all we can do is guess

Comment: Yes like I mentioned in my post above I double checked the permissions, they are in the manifest. Otherwise I wouldn't be able to get the app running on a real device.

Comment: can You suggest me the solution for this? I am facing the same problem..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set Command Line Artument in `Run Configuration` of Application.

[image: Run Configuration]